Is it possible to Monkey patch chrome's navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia in a chrome extension?
I am trying to write a chrome extension with manifest v3 that will detect if any website requests display media (Something like screensharing in a video conference) and records the mediaStream.
I've tried to run the following in a background service worker and a content script to no success.
// Intercept and detect screen share permission requests
export function interceptScreenShareRequest() {
    if (!navigator.mediaDevices || !navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia) {
        console.warn('getDisplayMedia not available');
        return;
      }

    const originalGetDisplayMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia;
    navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia = async function(constraints) {
      try {  
            // Log when screen share is requested
            logger(LogAction.RECORDING, 'Sharing detected. Starting recording of display...');

            const stream = await originalGetDisplayMedia.bind(navigator.mediaDevices)(constraints);
            recordStream(stream)

            return stream;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Screen share intercepted error:', error);
            throw error;
        }
    };
}

I'm always getting an error that getDisplayMedia does not exist on mediaDevices which I think makes sense because it shouldn't let me access getDisplayMedia unless I'm requesting access from the user... At least that's my understanding of it. Is this approach even feasible?

Yeah, sorry this question was solved by the linked duplicate answer. I tried putting "world": "MAIN in my manifest and my extension wouldn't build. Turns out I needed to update parcel. Works now. Thanks everyone.
